# How to add download sample below export option

Tags: magento2

Hi i have custom import pincode option in my module but i want to include a download sample file just below the upload field but am not sure how to achieve this
[image]

**Importpincode**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit\Tab;

class Importpincode extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()

    {


        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storemanager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __('Import Pincodes'),
                'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'file',
            'file',
            [
                'name'  => 'file',
                'label' => __('Upload File'),
                'title' => __('Upload File'),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Import Pincodes');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Form.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                ]
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Please avoid to used objectManger .

Comment: this is the demand

Comment: can you explain based on this code

Comment: i update your file please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit\Tab;

    class Importpincode extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {
        protected $_assetRepo;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
            parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare form
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        protected function _prepareForm()

        {

            $path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("vendor_module::importsample/sample.csv");

            $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $storemanager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                [
                    'legend' => __('Import Pincodes'),
                    'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
                ]
            );

            $importdata_script  = $fieldset->addField(
                'file',
                'file',
                [
                    'name'  => 'file',
                    'label' => __('Upload File'),
                    'title' => __('Upload File'),
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            );

            $importdata_script->setAfterElementHtml("
            <span id='sample-file-span' ><a id='sample-file-link' href='".$path."'  >Download Sample File</a></span>
            ");

            $this->setForm($form);
            return parent::_prepareForm();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare label for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return __('Import Pincodes');
        }

        /**
         * Prepare title for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return $this->getTabLabel();
        }

        /**
         * Can show tab in tabs
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Tab is hidden
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

put your sample file into your module give path **(Filename must be same)**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/img**

Here this line

```
$path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("VendoreName_ModuleName::img/your_sample_file_name.csv")
```

This line generate an URL. The Sample file which are in Our **VendoreName_ModuleName** in above path. And when you click on this generated link this download your sample file which are place into your module.

When you change in **__construct()** add / remove class you need to run this command.

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f 

php bin/magento c:f
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: $path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("VendoreName_ModuleName::img/your_sample_file_name.csv");

Comment: could you please explain this line

Comment: Update answer for more explaining about sample file url. Let me inform above solution is works for you ?

Comment: wait i will update my question

Comment: Let it check answer is updated base on your updated Question and also inform me it's works for you ?

Comment: am getting error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:775

Comment: You need to run above command which I added in above answer. Run and check it.

Comment: Are you still getting error ??

Comment: yes am still getting same error

Comment: You doing something wrong please check your code and try again.

Comment: Answer is updated